# Azure Redis shows active connection when unused

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I've just created a **dedicated** (not shared) Redis instance on Azure, and it already shows that there are active connections and operations. I haven't even gotten the chance to connect to it myself, so I know I don't have any active connections. I have SSL only enabled.

Especially the total commands sums up to a total of 15.39k - how can this be?

The "Hits and misses" and "Gets and sets" are 0.

I have included a screenshot of the monitoring windows in Azure:

[image: Screenshot of Metric: Total Commands, Connections and Memory Usage]

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Redis infrastructure connects to the cache regularly to verify that it is reachable (e.g. connectivity) and to also gather metrics around usage/statistics which are shown in the Azure portal, so this is expected behavior.